# Last drag event always return a negative number

Tags: javascript, html

Using the following script I get a **negative number** as last drag event using HTML5 feature.

Please try dragging red div here:

http://jsbin.com/bobezeveho/1/

When releasing the drag, div is not positioned properly.

I would like to know:

- What is the reasons for this issue?
- What could be the solution for this problem?

Notes: I am aware that I can just [check if a negative value has been returned](http://jsbin.com/racevejuba/1/) and skip it, but I would love understand what cause the problem.

```
 window.app = {
            config: {
                canDrag: false,
                cursorOffsetX: null,
                cursorOffsetY: null
            },
            reset: function () {
                this.config.cursorOffsetX = null;
                this.config.cursorOffsetY = null;
            },
            start: function () {
                document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++ dragstart')
                    this.config.cursorOffsetX = event.offsetX;
                    this.config.cursorOffsetY = event.offsetY;
                    this.adjustPostion(event);
                }.bind(this));
                document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++ drag')
                    this.adjustPostion(event);
                }.bind(this));
                document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++ dragend')
                    this.reset();
                }.bind(this));;
            },
            adjustPostion: function (event) {
                var elm = document.getElementById('target');
                elm.style.left = (event.pageX - this.config.cursorOffsetX) + 'px';
                elm.style.top = (event.pageY - this.config.cursorOffsetY) + 'px';
                console.log(event.pageX);
                console.log(event.pageY);
            }

        };
```

Comment: Using Firefox 39.0, I can't obtain any negative numbers.